# Function Pointer - variable not initialized

Tags: c, scanf

```
#include <stdio.h>

int Calc(int n1, int n2, int(*func) (int n1, int n2))
{
    return func(n1, n2);
}

int Plus(int n1, int n2)
{
    return n1 + n2;
}

int Minus(int n1, int n2)
{
    return n1 - n2;
}

int main(void)
{
    int n1, n2;
    int result;
    char mark;

    printf("입력 : ");
    scanf_s("%d", &n1);
    printf("choose function : ");
    scanf_s("%c", &mark, sizeof(mark));
    printf("입력 : ");
    scanf_s("%d", &n2);

    switch (mark)
    {
    case '+':
        result = Calc(n1, n2, Plus);
    case '-':
        result = Calc(n1, n2, Minus);
    }
    printf("%d\n", result);

    return 0;
}
```

I`m studying Function Pointer in C with simple code. I made it initialize variable result from using scanf_s, but it send me a error message that inform me variable result is not initialized. How can I fix this code?

Comment: This code is unfixable

Comment: @SeanF Why unfixable?

Comment: Just joking. Add a default case to your switch, just to make it compile. Initialize result there too

Comment: If u use a variable it must be initialized no matter what path is taken

Comment: Everything is fixable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two problems:

**1.** you leave `'\n'` in the input buffer after `scanf_s("%d", &n1);` which is then taken as your input to `scanf_s("%c", &mark, sizeof(mark));` You must remove the trailing newline before attempting read with `"%c"`. A simple `empty_stdin` function will do,

e.g.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void empty_stdin ()
{
    int c = getchar();

    while (c != '\n' && c != EOF)
        c = getchar();
}
...
    printf("입력 : ");
    scanf_s("%d", &n1);
    empty_stdin();           /* remove all extraneous chars from stdin */
    printf("choose function : ");
    scanf_s("%c", &mark, sizeof(mark));
```

**2.** You fail to include `break` at the end of each `switch` case causing automatic *fall-through* to the next `switch` case, you need,

e.g.

```
    switch (mark)
    {
    case '+':
        result = Calc(n1, n2, Plus);
        break;
    case '-':
        result = Calc(n1, n2, Minus);
        break;
    }
```

Putting it altogether, you could do:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void empty_stdin ()
{
    int c = getchar();

    while (c != '\n' && c != EOF)
        c = getchar();
}

int Calc(int n1, int n2, int(*func) (int n1, int n2))
{
    return func(n1, n2);
}

int Plus(int n1, int n2)
{
    return n1 + n2;
}

int Minus(int n1, int n2)
{
    return n1 - n2;
}

int main(void)
{
    int n1, n2;
    int result = 0;
    char mark;

    printf("입력 : ");
    scanf_s("%d", &n1);
    empty_stdin();
    printf("choose function : ");
    scanf_s("%c", &mark, sizeof(mark));
    printf("입력 : ");
    scanf_s("%d", &n2);

    switch (mark)
    {
    case '+':
        result = Calc(n1, n2, Plus);
        break;
    case '-':
        result = Calc(n1, n2, Minus);
        break;
    }
    printf("%d\n", result);

    return 0;
}
```

(**NOTE:** you must also verify the **return** of each `scanf` to insure you have valid input -- that is left to you. Also note, you could ignore leading *whitespace* -- including `'\n'` -- by including a space before your format specifier, e.g. `" %c"`, but that doesn't protect against a *matching* failure from your prior input -- ideally, you should `empty_stdin()` following each input with `scanf` to protect against that case and ready the input buffer for your next input.)

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/fnpointer
입력 : 2
choose function : +
입력 : 3
5
```

Comment: Sometimes it is required. `:)`

Comment: Not this time :-)

Comment: What are you saying? You can always simply `" %c"` to each whitespace, but you are screwed if the first entry is `1 two three`. You should `empty_stdin()` after each input -- the example above just illustrates his problem -- do you have something else you are thinking about? I can't read your mind.

Comment: Keep it simple kiss

Comment: Keep it simple kiss

Comment: I found that when I use " %c" instead of "%c", i can use this program. thank you guys

Comment: Yes, that is correct, but understand the limits of using just `" %c"`, if there is anything other than just `'\n'` left in `stdin`, your code will fail. Example, if the user enters `"5a"` by mistake. That's why you should remove ALL characters for robust code, not just rely on removing the `'\n'`.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't initialized result variable, you used scanf_s for n1,n2, but you didn't do anything with result so compiler complain about

Comment: but I tried to use function Calc - include function Plus and Minus - to initialize result

Comment: You should clean buffer after scanning %d, because there is a \n after the scanning